# Online search bar values after export from excel not clicking automatically tag identify wrong

Tags: excel, vba

I am exporting values from two cells online on a webpage which is running correctly. However, I have to manually press enter as Click is not automatically working in ElementbyId tag selection ("locationSearchTextBox").
After wards, I manually press enter and inspect element to import the elevation result back to excel.

I need help in automating these final two steps. I am new in learning about tag classes, id name etc. Probably might be choosing wrong due to ignorance. Help is appreciated.

```
Sub elevation_finder()
Dim elevation As Long
Dim ieobject As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlElement As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ieobject = New InternetExplorer
ieobject.Visible = True
ieobject.navigate "https://www.freemaptools.com/elevation-finder.htm"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Header")
    ieobject.document.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox").Value = _
    .Range("B2").Value & "," & .Range("C2").Value

    ieobject.document.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox").Click
    ieobject.document.getElementById("0EGu2eqKt6").Click

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a solution. But there are problems with timing. I already have an idea, but it's too late now. Tomorrow I'll see if the problems can be solved the way I want them to be. How many coords do you want to work with?

Comment: thanks. for every row there are two coordinates and the column can have a max. of 20 coordinates for 20 different IDs. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the timing problems with loops. This should do what you want. I have tested it with nearly 2.000 coords in one go. Please read the comments carefully:

```
Sub ElevationFinder()

'Columns
Const colLat As Long = 2     'Latitude
Const colLon As Long = 3     'Longitude
Const colEleInM As Long = 4  'Elevation in meter
Const colEleInFt As Long = 5 'Elevation in feet

Const url As String = "https://www.freemaptools.com/elevation-finder.htm"

Dim browser As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeDropDown As Object
Dim nodeSearchTextBox As Object
Dim nodeSubmitButton As Object
Dim nodeClearMapButton As Object
Dim nodeElevationLabel As Object

Dim tableLongLat As Worksheet
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim coords As String
Dim elevation As String
Dim splitArray() As String
Dim timeout As Double
Dim start As Double

  start = Timer
  Set tableLongLat = Sheets("Header") 'Table with coords
  currentRow = 2 'Start row

  'Jump to first row for visual monitoring
  tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, 1).Select

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = False 'If you want to see what happens in IE, set this to True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Manual break to load the map (dynamic content)
  'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))

  'Shortening the call of the html document
  Set htmlDoc = browser.document

  'Get dropdown for selecting what to search for
  'The default setting is "Latitude,Logitude", but when we switch to another entry,
  'the required "Estimate Elevation" button to send the request appears. After that
  'we switch back to "Latitude,Logitude". The button remains in place
  Set nodeDropDown = htmlDoc.getElementById("locationSearchSelect")

  'Select "Free Text Search" and trigger the change event of the dropdown
  'Triggering is necessary because otherwise the change will not be recognized
  'by the page and the button will not appear
  nodeDropDown.selectedIndex = 5
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeDropDown, "change")

  'Switch back to "Latitude,Logitude"
  nodeDropDown.selectedIndex = 0
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeDropDown, "change")

  'Get input field for search text
  Set nodeSearchTextBox = htmlDoc.getElementById("locationSearchTextBox")

  'Get "Estimate Elevation" button
  Set nodeSubmitButton = htmlDoc.getElementById("locationSearchButton")

  'Get the button to clear the map from last set coords
  'There are 5 buttons on the page with the css class "fmtbutton"
  'The third is the button to clear the map (index of a node list begins at 0)
  Set nodeClearMapButton = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("fmtbutton")(2)

  'Go through all rows filled with coords
  Do While tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colLat).Value <> ""
    'Scroll for visual monitoring
    If currentRow > 14 Then
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
    End If

    'Get coords of current row
    coords = tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colLat).Value & "," & tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colLon).Value

    'Enter coords to search field
    nodeSearchTextBox.Value = coords

    'Click "Estimate Elevation" button
    nodeSubmitButton.Click

    'Get elevation from label on map
    'The elevation also appears above the search field,
    'but there it is more difficult to read the value
    '
    'Start time for timeout if coordinates are invalid
    timeout = Timer
    '
    'To retrieve multiple elevation information from the map,
    'coordinates must be set and deleted alternately. Since
    'setting coordinates takes different amounts of time and
    'it also takes different amounts of time to delete coordinates
    'from the map, loops are used. These ensure that the shortest
    'possible time periods are used. This has something to do with
    'server communication. The alternative would be to set a blanket
    'pause, which would slow down the macro a lot, because the
    'estimated maximum value would have to be used
    Do
      'At first we try to get the label
      Set nodeElevationLabel = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-tooltip")(0)
      'Then we try to read out the text
      'If no label was there yet, no text
      'can be read out. Therefore, error
      'handling is temporarily switched off
      On Error Resume Next
      elevation = Trim(nodeElevationLabel.innertext)
      On Error GoTo 0
    'Let the loop run until either a elevation information
    'has been read out or the timeout takes effect
    Loop Until elevation <> "" Or Timer - timeout > 5 'Timeout in seconds

    If elevation <> "" Then
      'Elevation information come as string: 210.0 m / 689.0 feet
      'The two values will be separated
      splitArray = Split(elevation, "/")
      splitArray(0) = Trim(Replace(splitArray(0), "m", ""))
      splitArray(1) = Trim(Replace(splitArray(1), "feet", ""))

      'Write the elevation in meter to the Excel sheet
      tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colEleInM).NumberFormat = "#,##0.0 ""m"""
      tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colEleInM).Value = splitArray(0)

      'Write the elevation in feet to the Excel sheet
      tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colEleInFt).NumberFormat = "#,##0.0 ""ft"""
      tableLongLat.Cells(currentRow, colEleInFt).Value = splitArray(1)

      'Click the clear map button
      nodeClearMapButton.Click
      'The loop mechanism, as explained above
      'No timeout necessary, because the label
      'will be gone in any case
      Do
        Set nodeElevationLabel = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-tooltip")(0)
      Loop Until nodeElevationLabel Is Nothing
    End If

    'Prepare for next coords
    elevation = ""
    Erase splitArray
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Loop

  'Clean up
  browser.Quit
  'MsgBox Timer - start
End Sub
```

This procedure to trigger the change event:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ossmoss At least some feedback would be nice.